# Помогите с решением проблемы: python: can't open file 'sqlmap.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, kali-linux

Не могу запустить скрипт `sqlmap` при попытке запустить командой

```
python sqlmap.py -h
```

появляется ошибка

```
python: can not open file 'sqlmap.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Как только не пробовал исправить, но все одно и тоже.
Единственный способ запустить скрипт это команда:

```
/usr/share/kali-menu/exec-in-shell sqlmap -u
```

Но здесь при использовании некоторых функций появляется ошибка (как понял что нужен `python`)
Что это и можно ли это как то исправить?

Comment: `-h` это же `help`, зачем вы с этим ключом вызываете `python`?

Comment: -h просто для примера

Comment: А запускаете вы эту команду из того каталога, где лежит ваш файл `sqlmap.py`?

Comment: просто укажите полный путь к файлу

Comment: да только при использование команды python sqlmap ошибка работает только когда полний путь к файлу указываю / usr / share / kali-menu / exec-in-shell sqlmap

Comment: что python не нужен ?

Comment: `/usr/share/kali-menu/exec-in-shell sqlmap ` здесь Вы указываете полный путь к `exec-in-shell`

Comment: для того чтобы запустить через python укажите полный путь к `sqlmap.py`

Comment: [~/Рабочий стол/sqlmap]
└─$ python3 /home/kali2020/Рабочий стол/sqlmap/sqlmap.py -u "https://www.hansovd.com" --batch --banner                                                 2 ⨯
python3: can't open file '/home/kali2020/Рабочий': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Попробуйте путь в кавычки взять, но вообще пробелы в путях это зло: `python3 "/home/kali2020/Рабочий стол/sqlmap/sqlmap.py"` или `python3 "/home/kali2020/Рабочий стол/sqlmap/"sqlmap.py` я точно не помню как правильно

Comment: Большое спасибо за указанную помощь получилось решить проблему способом полного удаление приложение и вновь копированного  с github в /usr/share/kali-menu/. Проблема оказалась в устрои ном приложения sqlmap в kali-linux при замене на новый все работает